# git clone --mirror with Ansible 2.4

Tags: git, ansible

How do you do this via the git module in ansible 2.4?
I've looked at the doco http://docs.ansible.com/ansible/latest/git_module.html there is no option for `mirror` cloning.

Is there any other way to do it without having to run straight up shell commands.. 
Currently I have something that looks like this..

```
- name: Clone git repo
  git:
    repo: ssh://git@github.com/foo/bar.git
    key_file: /home/deploy/.ssh/id_rsa
    dest: /path/to/repo
    accept_hostkey: true
    update: yes
    version: master
    bare: no
  become_user: deploy
  when: repo_created.changed
```

I like the nice config switches to accept host keys etc.
The alternative I think is something like this.. (untested as yet)

```
- name: Test if github is a known host
  shell: ssh-keygen -l -f /home/deploy/.ssh/known_hosts -F github.com
  register: github_host_is_known
  sudo_user: deploy
  ignore_errors: True
  changed_when: github_host_is_known.rc != 0
- name: Add githubs key to known hosts
  shell: ssh-keyscan -H github.com >> /home/deploy/.ssh/known_hosts
  when: github_host_is_known.rc != 0
  sudo_user: deploy
- name: "Clone repo"
  command: git clone --mirror git@github.com:foo/bar.git /path/to/repo
  sudo_user: deploy
  when: repo_created.changed
```

Is that my only / best option?

Answer (score 3):

So so far this is the necest way I've been able to clone a mirror repo using Ansible 2.4

```
- name: Add githubs key to known hosts
  known_hosts:
    path: /home/deploy/.ssh/known_hosts
    name: github.com
    key: "{{ lookup('pipe', 'ssh-keyscan -t rsa github.com') }}"
    state: present
  sudo_user: deploy

- name: change the owner of the known_hosts file to deploy user
# because https://github.com/ansible/ansible/issues/29331
  file:
    path: /home/deploy/.ssh/known_hosts
    owner: deploy
    group: deploy
    mode: 0644

- name: Clone repo with --mirror
  environment:
    GIT_SSH_COMMAND: ssh -i /home/deploy/.ssh/id_rsa # Needs git 2.3 + for this to work
  command: git clone --mirror git@github.com:foo/bar.git /path/to/repo
  sudo_user: deploy
```

This feels not so bad. Would still be nice to have a mirror option.

Edit: spoke too soon, looks like the known_hosts module alters the files permissions. :( now feels more hacky